# Migrate mongodb to Google Cloud Compute Cluster

Tags: mongodb, data-migration, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a mongodb in a replica set running with a cloud provider called [compose.io](http://compose.io/).

I just created a new Google cloud compute mongodb cluster using [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mongodb/intro)

I want to copy all the data in my compose database to the compute instance.

One path I have been following has led me to get a file system backup of the running database and store it locally. I have opened that database locally and executed mongodump (I didn't seem to have permission to do that against the remote database) so I have the output of `mongodump` and a file system copy of the database stored on my machine.

I have no idea how to get any of this in to the compute cluster I created. I don't seem to be able to run `mongorestore` although figuring that out is still my main path at the moment. I am getting authentication errors which may be my not getting the command right or a database configuration issue. I am not sure yet.

I tried `mongorestore` from my local machine to the machine holding the primary database in the replica set.

Edit:

The last thing I tried was copy `scp` the mongodump output on to that machine and run `mongorestore` there.

I got this error:

`2015-01-28T23:35:40.303+0000    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, ns: "admin.system.users", name: "_id_" }
Error creating index admin.system.users: 13 err: "not authorized to create index on admin.system.users"
Aborted`

Now I don't seem to be able to run any commands in mongo that require any kind of privileges, such as list database. Tried passing credentials for users that existed in the original database but that is not working so far.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how you tried to execute mongorestore and resulting errors?

Comment: Hi @VilasJagannath, sorry about the lack of detail there. Just coming back to this now. Got a little further but seems I am stuck on a privileges issue. Trying to figure that one out at the moment. Updated my question with some details.

Comment: @Ruairi Did you figure out what's causing the "Error creating index" issue? I'm running into the same thing doing a mongorestore to Modulus from a Meteor db dump.

Comment: Sorry @DaveRoma. I ended up giving up on this particular one. I was trying to migrate some data but it wasn't really important to me and I didn't want to waste too much time on it although I'd still love to know what I was doing wrong. I've completely lost where I was on it so I can't even look in to it again if I wanted to. I'm going to delete this question as I don't this it will help anyone.

Comment: @Ruairi This was the approach I took that worked for me - although our issues were somewhat different they share commonalities and this may be useful to you or anyone else experience similar issues http://blog.daveroma.com/export-meteor-database-to/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible fix.

Turn off auth in mongod.conf:

```
# mongod.conf

#auth=false
noauth=true
```

Run the mongorestore, then restart mongod with auth enabled.